# How to properly define properties in ExtJS custom class

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I am attempting to create a reusable title bar for our grids. This will require a couple of properties which can be set when the grid title bar is used. The problem I am running into is that the property is undefined when I attempt to use it.

I looked at how ExtJS appears to do this and saw that they set up their properties in the config block. So I tried that with no luck. I have also tried removing the config block and adding the property with the same result.

```
Ext.define('ERM.view.mastersite.GridTitleBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.TitleBar',
    xtype: 'gridtitlebar',
    margin: '0 0 20 0',
    shadow: true,
    cls: 'x-big',

    style: {
        border: 'solid lightgrey 2px'
    },

    config: {
        addNewToolTip: 'test',
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        iconCls: 'md-icon-add-circle',
        text: 'Add',
        align: 'right',
        tooltip: this.parent.addNewToolTip,
    }],
});
```

I'm expecting the tool tip to show "test" by default, or if the default is overridden, I'm expecting it to show the overridden string.

**Edit**
Second attempt based on the answers below.

```
Ext.define('ERM.view.mastersite.GridTitleBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.TitleBar',
    xtype: 'gridtitlebar',
    margin: '0 0 20 0',
    shadow: true,
    cls: 'x-big',

    style: {
        border: 'solid lightgrey 2px'
    },

    config: {
        addNewToolTip: 'test',
    },

    initialize: function () {
        const me = this;
        me.items = [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Add',
            iconCls: 'md-icon-add-circle',
            tooltip: me.getAddNewToolTip(),
        }];

        this.callParent();
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using modern toolkit use initialize method instead of initComponent

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly defining the property. Your problem is the way you are accessing it.

At the time of building the `items` construct, the `this` context is whatever has loaded the file - probably the boot loader. Strangely enough, that won't have your new property.

In order to access properties of your new class/object, you need to define the `items` construct after the object is created. One good location for that is in the `initComponent` method.

```
Ext.define('ERM.view.mastersite.GridTitleBar', {
  // in here, the 'this' context is whatever loaded the file. 
...
  config: {
    addNewToolTip: 'test',
  },
...
  initComponent: function() {
    // In here, like most methods in ExtJS, the 'this' context is the owning instance.
    this.items = [{
        xtype: 'button',
...
        // Oh, and it's a good idea to use the accessors for config variables
        tooltip: this.getAddNewToolTip()
    }]
    // don't forget to call the parent.
    this.callParent(arguments);
});
```

Comment: Learning how the `this` keyword works in JavaScript, and how the relevant context is determined, will save you a lot of grief in the long run. It's _not_ like Java in any way, and will trip you up if you're not careful.

Comment: I've tried doing what you have above and my button disappeared. I've moved the items into the initComponent and made sure to call the parent.

Comment: I edited the wrong comment. :/ But I added my attempt.